# DB scheme for the online marketing

Tags: sql

I'm trying to project DB sheme for online market: [what I have now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyfiH.png) but problem is when I add new category of product, which has its own set of product datails, I need create new table with product details. I just search for advice db scheme without db administrations.

Comment: What schema alterations have you tried and what doesn't convince you in them? StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).
Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Regardless the fact this question should have been asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), the question itself could be flagged as `primarly opinion based` because there isn't an optimal DB scheme as it varies from subject to subject.

Answer (score 0):

Add a feild on product details to link it to the category